# Create Public custom settings via REST API

Tags: rest-api, sobject, customsetting

First, is it possible to create a custom object without using Metadata SOAP API ? As per my reading until now it is not possible.

I know for a fact, one can create ApexTrigger using REST API.
Since I want to keep using REST API for all my operations, is it possible to create a custom setting such that it supports getUpdated() and getDeleted() methods which happens when '**repliceatable**' field is **true** for objects ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating a custom object using REST API](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/20763/creating-a-custom-object-using-rest-api)

Comment: Not really. The real question is how to create a custom-setting similar to a custom object such that getUpdated() and getDeleted() REST APIs work on the custom-setting?

Comment: Do you mean custom setting data records of the metadata/custom object description ?

Comment: Custom settings are similar to custom objects as per my reading. I want to know if I can create Custom Settings using REST API ? I know for a fact, custom objects are created using metadata API only which is in SOA Protocol. Is it the case with Custom Settings too?